# data and label json array not showing up on chart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am using highcharts to display a bar chart of my data which i am getting from a json file.

I tried following highcharts example for a bar chart for some reason mine is not displaying anything on the chart nor giving me an error.

This is how i am loading my json data for labels and data values - i am returning the data that i want but the issue with display:

```
chartLabel: any[] = [];
chartValue: any[] = [];

this.serviceFile.getData().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.result = data;
          this.result.forEach(graph =>{
            this.chartLabel.push(graph.labelName);
            this.chartValue.push(graph.value);
          })
      });
```

**HTML:**

```
<chart [options]="options"></chart>
```

chart options:

```
this.options = {
          chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                margin: 75
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: this.chartLabel,
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: this.chartValue
            }]
      };
```

I am not sure if the way i created the arrays of my json data are appropriate for the highcharts chart.

I noticed in my console.log the way the data prints out is different which i believe is the cause of the problem and maybe some light on this matter will help: 
printout for this.chartValue:

```
(3)[12,34,54]
```

what this should look like is:

```
12,34,54
```

Comment: What does the code that actually creates the chart look like?  Have you verified the values in this.chartValue and this.chartLabel?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird yes i verified the values in `this.chartValue` and `this.chartLabel`. The code above is the code that creates the chart , i just have it in my component file. when i run the code i get the title and series label showing but the chart itself no bars.

Comment: What is the this.chartValue? series.data must be an array of numbers/arrays/objects.